# .GIF re edit! Can't figure it out!

Tags: graphics, image, animation, photoshop

http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/1892/hatersgonna.gif
That is the photo..

I am trying to cut around it so its a little smaller and make him walk the opposite direction. The reason I am doing this is for a VBulletin forum signature since it marquees left to right.

I have tried editing the animation in Photoshop and I flipped the canvas to horizontal... I can't figure this out.. I've been at it for HOURS. hah

Also if anyone can make it just a little darker that would be amazing.

"no I'm not asking for free help" but any help would be great

Thank you so much

Comment: I just have to say I am *so* glad "forum signatures" aren't permitted on SO.

Comment: This belongs on super-user, right?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done easily in adobe image ready.
First open the gif in image ready it will show all the frames.
Transform all frames to invert from left to right so that the guy faces in opposite direction.
you can add common extra layer with dark outline to all frames .now again save this as gif.
Hope that helps.